# Why is CompletableFuture.get() blocked by Thread.sleep()?

Tags: java

I have no idea why the CompletableFuture.get() is blocked by the Thread.sleep()? Why does the size of LinkedBlockingQueue will affect the probability of TimeoutException ?

Thanks.

```
import com.google.common.collect.Queues;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class TaskSleepTest {

    private static final ThreadPoolExecutor EXECUTOR = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4, 16, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, Queues.newLinkedBlockingQueue(10));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            new Thread(() -> {
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 2000; i1++) {
                    Supplier<Void> task = () -> {
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                        return null;
                    };
                    testSleep(task);
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    private static void testSleep(Supplier<Void> task) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, EXECUTOR).whenComplete((t, throwable) -> {
                if (throwable != null) {
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }).get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("success ----------" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + (end - start));
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("TimeoutException ----------" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + (end - start));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("Exception ----------" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + (end - start));
        }
    }
}
```

When the queue size less that 16 it works fine and be able to get result within 200~300ms. However when I adjust queue size to 30 I get TimeoutException.

Comment: If your queue is small, your tasks are simply rejected, if your queue is large, then `get` waits for the task to be picked up by a thread in the thread pool, which makes `get` time out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] why the CompletableFuture.get() is blocked by the Thread.sleep()?

In your code the `Thread.sleep()` is executed before the work task produces a result:

```
Supplier<Void> task = () -> {
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(200);  // this is the sleep
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return null;  // here the work task produces the result
};
```

`Completable.get()` retrieves the result that this work task produces. It cannot retrieve that result before the work task has produced it and is therefore delayed by the `Thread.sleep()`.

---

> When the queue size less that 16 it works fine and be able to get result within 200~300ms. However when I adjust queue size to 30 I get TimeoutException.

This happens because of the interaction between

- number of threads creating work tasks (30)
- ThreadExecutor core pool size (4)
- ThreadExecutor maximum pool size (16)
- maximum capacity of the work queue (10, 30)

The ThreadExecutor spawns up to *core pool size* threads as soon as work arrives (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html):

> Core and maximum pool sizes
>
> A ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically adjust the pool size [...]. When a new task is submitted in method execute(Runnable), if fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle. Else if fewer than maximumPoolSize threads are running, a new thread will be created to handle the request only if the queue is full. [...]

If the maximum queue size is low (10) the 30 threads creating new work tasks will quickly generate more than corePoolSize + queueSize (4 + 10 = 14) work tasks and the ThreadPoolExecutor will start more threads up to the maximum pool size (16).

At this point you have 16 threads executing work tasks and a queue of another 10 work tasks. Of your 30 threads creating new work tasks 26 are blocked (because their work tasks are either executing or waiting in the work queue), the other 4 threads are creating work tasks that get rejected (because the work queue is full).

If a work tasks is completed, the thread that executed it fetches the next work task from the work queue which has been sitting there for about 200ms (it will never much longer because the work queue size is small compared to the number of threads in the ThreadPoolExecutor) and therefore can successfully completed within the time limit of 1000ms that the creating thread is willing to wait.

The whole picture changes when you raise the maximum work queue size to 30. In this case the work queue will never be full and the ThreadPoolExecutor will only start corePoolSize threads (i.e. 4 threads):

- you have 30 threads creating work tasks (within a few milliseconds)
- the ThreadPoolExecutor will create 4 threads to handle 4 of these work tasks
- 26 work tasks will be stored in the work queue
- after 200ms the 4 threads of the ThreadPoolExecutor will have finished 4 work tasks and will pick the next work tasks.
- after 400ms the 4 threads of the ThreadPoolExecutor will have finished 8 work tasks.
- after 600ms the 4 threads of the ThreadPoolExecutor will have finished 12 work tasks.
- after 800ms the 4 threads of the ThreadPoolExecutor will have finished 16 work tasks.
- after 1000ms the 4 threads of the ThreadPoolExecutor will have finished 20 work tasks.

And now 10 of those 30 work tasks that where created during the first few milliseconds will start to time out.